# How can I pause and continue a TPL task?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have scenario where I have a couple of background tasks (TPL tasks) which run on their own individual schedules. Task 1 is deemed to have a higher priority than Task 2.

If the scheduler wants to run Task 1, I need to check if Task 2 is running and pause it while Task 1 completes execution.

Is this even possible? If yes, how can I achieve this?

Comment: This is not what the TPL was designed for. Might be possible to approach this with waithandles but it seems like going the wrong way. Re-examine the design that got you here.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I was not sure either hence worth an ask. My current design has only "Task 1" present and I have implemented that using traditional Threads. I have just started working on TPL and looked at the Wait and Continue methods and was hoping there was some "easy" way to achieve what I had asked for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use signaling constructs to achieve this.

```
static ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

var Task1=Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Executing Task 1");
    Thread.Sleep(2000); //A Long running operation
    Console.WriteLine("Task 1 Completed");
    mre.Set(); //signal the task completion to task 2.
});


var Task2=Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    if (!Task1.IsCompleted) //check if task1 is completed.
    {
        mre.WaitOne(); //wait until Task 1 Completes
        Console.WriteLine("Executing Task 2");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Task 2 Completed");    
        doSomeTask();
    }
     else
    {
        //Task 1 is already completed
        doSomeTask();
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. Am I correct in understanding this would not help if task 2 has already started? In my case, both these tasks would actually start from different threads within the application (at a different place altogether).

Comment: do you mean to say that there is no guarantee on which thread will start first?

Answer (score 2):

The easy, non-blocking way is `Task.Delay`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay(v=vs.110).aspx

```
// Some code here

await Task.Delay(2000); // Pause for 2 seconds, without blocking

// Code to execute after waiting
```